# creating 2D javascript array from ajax php call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, multidimensional-array

I have a mysql table with image data in.

I want to retrieve the image data and push into a javascript array.

There are two fields that I want to put into the array and they are image_ref, and image_name
I know I need a 2D array for this and I need to retrive the data from the db using ajax and JSON.

I am not sure how to complete this.

I know I need to call the php page with a JSON ajax call

js:

```
var imagesArray[];

$.getJSON("get_image_data.php")
    .done(function(data) { 
  /*THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP---*/
});
```

get_image_data.php page

```
include("connect.php"); 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE live='1' ORDER BY insertDate DESC");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query){
     echo json_encode(array("a" => $row['image_ref'], "b" => $row['image_name'])); 
}
```

I have highlighted where I need help in getting the returned data into the stockImages array.

Can anyone show me the light?

thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you want to put them in a 2D array ? A 1D array of objects is clearer and JSON allows you to do that easily.

Comment: I need a 2 d array as there are two fields for each image so the array would be imagesArray[0][0] etc I need the image_name for showing the image on the page and the image_ref for referencing it back to the db for any changes i.e. if i delete the image the field 'live' needs to be changed and I would use the image_ref to do this as uploaded user images can have the same name

Comment: You do not need a 2D array since an object itself is some kind of array with string used as indexes. And your PHP code is wrong. You can't combine associative arrays and fetch_array(). I suggest you learn languages and read documentations before using them and asking questions.

Comment: How am I supposed to learn without teachers and getting advice from here is asking for teachers as I stated in my post, I need help

Comment: There are plenty of AJAX, MySQL and JSON tutorials on internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling `json_encode()` multiple times in your loop, you are creating lots of singular bits of JSON. You should aim at creating and transmitting one transfer object, like this:

```
include("connect.php"); 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE live='1' ORDER BY insertDate DESC");
$images = array(); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query){
    $images[] = array("a" => $row['image_ref'], "b" => $row['image_name']); 
}
echo json_encode($images);
```

This will give you one JSON array, through which you can loop in your client side Javascript.

Comment: When I run the code with your updated php I alert the returned data and it echos as data=[object,Object][object,Object] can you tell me why it is doing this

Comment: Yes, that's OK. You are getting a Javascript object as a return - remember that JSON means Javascript OBJECT notation. It might have been wrong to use the term "array" above. In order to properly inspect the data variable, use a tool like Firebug and `console.log(data)` instead of `alert(data)`

Comment: the console in chrome returns  [Object, Object]
0: Object
1: Object
length: 2  in firefox the console logs nothing. How do I use the data to create an image on the page because when I do this

Comment: ah i finally get it after a week of scratching my head. To utilise the json object i have to call 'array[0].b' or 'array[0].b'

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is PHP that is wrong, 'cause on JS you will have the array you need directly in "data".

You PHP code should look like:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE live='1' ORDER BY insertDate DESC");
$result = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query){
    $result[] = array("a" => $row['image_ref'], "b" => $row['image_name']); 
}
echo(json_encode($result));
```

Comment: @Katran I have changed the php to match yours but I am getting an error from my javascript   $.getJSON("get_image_data.php").done(function(data) { 
  stockImagesArray=data;       
        });   it errors saying  --
TypeError: $.getJSON(...).done is not a function @...